# sed copy substring from fixed position and copy it in front of line

Tags: bash, csv, sed, substring

I'm dealing with many csv files and I can't find a way with sed to select a substring at a fixed position *(chars 9-16)* and copy it at the beginning of the line.

This is what I have:

`ABC09638006924340017;SOME_TEXT;SOME_OTHER_TEXT`

This is what I need:

`00692434;ABC09638006924340017;SOME_TEXT;SOME_OTHER_TEXT`

The following code in sed gives the substring I need *(00692434)* but overwrites the whole line:

`sed 's/^.{8}(.{8}).*/\1/')`

I'm already using sed to "clean" the linestrings and inserting some variables, called in a bash script that at the end imports data in postgres. This is why I would prefer to remain within sed, but any hint will be greatly appreciated as I'm not a real expert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the curly braces (`\{\}`) as well as the parentheses (`\(\)`) and also append the original string (`&`) in the replacement:

```
text="ABC09638006924340017;SOME_TEXT;SOME_OTHER_TEXT"
echo $text | sed "s/^.\{8\}\(.\{8\}\).*/\1;&/"
```

Output:

```
00692434;ABC09638006924340017;SOME_TEXT;SOME_OTHER_TEXT
```

Since you want to extract a fixed-length substring at a fixed position, you could also do this with just bash-builtins:

```
text="ABC09638006924340017;SOME_TEXT;SOME_OTHER_TEXT"
echo "${text:8:8};$text"
```

Comment: Thank you Ansgar, by reading potong's answer and your I understand how wrong were my sed's approaches in this case (quite a rookie here). I knew there was a simple solutions to focus on, but didn't believe it could be that short: ";&".

Comment: Worked fine, thank you. Hope I don't break any etiquette by posting my final sed string: `sed -e 's/; /;/g;s/ ;/;/g;s/^.\{8\}\(.\{8\}\).*/\1;&/;s/^/'"$STRING"';/' $file > $TEMP$file`code``

Comment: `s/; /;/g;s/ ;/;/g` could be simplified to `s/\s\+;\s\+/;/g`, and prepending the result with $STRING could be included with the second expression: `s/^.\{8\}\(.\{8\}\).*/'"$STRING"';\1;&/` (or `s/^.{8}(.{8}).*/'"$STRING"';\1;&/` when using the `-r` option).

Comment: Thank you for fine-tuning my sed string. I'm using bash-builtins to extract 2 fixed-length substrings from the first line of each file that become the variable $STRING that I pass to sed before processing all lines (these substrings remain the same for the whole file). I'm using sed for the rest because I was thinking is faster or more reliable than using bash-builtins. May I ask, by your experience, if my assertion about performance is wrong?

Comment: No, `sed` should be a little faster.

Answer (score 4):

This migth work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^.{8}(.{8})/\1;&/' file
```

Comment: Thank you potong, I'll try it in my script and will let you know.